# Ended up with 'empathise'

Tags: word, no-computers

I started off with a one-letter English language word. For every step, I added one letter of my choice, and re-arranged the letters to make a new word. By the end, I had:

> EMPATHISE

What was the word I started with, and how did I get to the word that I ended with?

My solution is probably not unique, so will be interesting to see if there are other paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nine letters:

> EMPATHISE

Eight letters:

> SHIPMATE

Seven letters:

> ATHEISM

Six letters:

> THEISM

Five letters:

> TIMES

Four letters:

> TIME

Three letters:

> TIE

Two letters:

> IT

One letter:

> I.

I did find another path from the same six-letter word on down, but it involves a couple of rude words.

Comment: The eight-letter word seems to be unique.

Comment: @RobPratt Yep, I figured that out too. Not sure whether the seven-letter one is or not.

Comment: No: rot13(CNFGVZR)

Comment: Nice, and fast. Slight difference in the 5 letter word, but you get into all kinds of anagrams possible at the lower levels.

Comment: @RobPratt but from there, is there any way down through six-letter and five-letter words? I couldn't find one.

Comment: Yes: rot13(GNZVFR)

Comment: According to the dictionary I was looking at, rot13(zngrfuvc) and rot13(urzcvrfg) are other possible 8-letter words.